# How can i prevent an empty OpenGL Window when activating multisampling (Windows)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I'm developing an application using OpenGL 3D visualization in Visual Studio 10. The control for the visualization is written in C++. 
When initializing an OpenGL Window, i try to enable Multisampling by directly using the extensions (wglChoosePixelFormatARB).

As i already learned, you first have to create a dummy Window and call "wglChoosePixelFormatARB" with the appropriate attributes. Later i use the "pixelformat" which is returned by this method to create the real 3D Window. In my code the call looks something like this:

```
const int attribs[] = {
    WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
    WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
    WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
    WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
    WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
    WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
    WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
    WGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS_ARB, GL_TRUE,
    WGL_SAMPLES_ARB, m_multiSample,
    0
};

if(wglChoosePixelFormatARB(hdc,attribs,NULL,1,&pixelformat,&numFormats)!=0 && pixelformat>0) {
    m_pixelFormat = pixelformat;
}
```

then i call `SetPixelFormat` for the new window with the pixelformat found previously.

The whole procedure works well for some configurations, but with specific Combinations of GPUs and values for `WGL_SAMPLES_ARB` i receive values for pixelformat which seem to be ok, but when i create a new window with this pixelformat, this window stays empty (white or gray) - e.g. when using the Intel HD Graphics in my notebook with a setting of 8 for `WGL_SAMPLES_ARB` the window stays white - using 4 works perfectly.

My problem now is that i could not find a way to check from within the program if the current pixelformat setting is valid or not. I would greatly appreciate any help on how to handle these situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken directly from the WGL spec:

> "If no matching formats are found then nNumFormats is set to zero and the function returns TRUE."

What you **really** want to do to verify that a matching pixel format was found is test the value of 'numFormats'... since you are requesting a perfect matching pixel format here, if numFormats is anything other than 1 after you call wglChoosePixelFormat (...), then you know something is wrong. Effectively, change the pixelformat > 0 condition to numFormats == 1.

On a side note, I don't even bother using the window system to setup multi-sampling in my software anymore -- it is much more convenient to use framebuffer objects, you can change your anti-aliasing on the fly without having to create a new render context that way.

At any rate, multi-sample capabilities vary from card to card and even configuration. On AMD hardware, in a CrossFire configuration you can do 16x multisample, while single GPU solutions only provide 8x max.

You'll probably have to do multiple pixel format queries before you can identify the full range of MSAA sample counts supported on any given host. FBOs are definitely more convenient :)

Comment: Thank's a lot for pointing that out. It was right under my nose.. Also i'm going to try using framebuffer objects when i can spare some time for it.